# Matching response to request using UrlFetchApp.fetchAll

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

Im trying to validate bunch of urls that are stored in google spreadsheet using Google App Script. Since there are many urls to validate and `UrlFetchApp.fetch` does not execute http request in parallel, it becomes slow. So I would like to use `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll`, which works asynchronously.

But, there is problem:

```
var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(["http://www.bar.com", "http://www.foo.com"]);
responses[0] // Is this response from http://www.bar.com or http://www.foo.com
responses[1] // Is this response from http://www.bar.com or http://www.foo.com
```

Now responses is array of `HTTPResponse` objects. But to give user feedback, I would need to indicate responses that fail.  But problem is that in response, there is no reference to request or URL.  So problem is that I have array of responses but I'm unable to find URL this response came from.  Responses array is not in same order as given to argument.

Comment: When ``UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requestArray)`` is run, the response is put in an array, and the index of response array is corresponding to that of ``requestArray``. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide sample script for replicating your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike I think you understood correctly. And yes, response array can be in different order. So i cannot match them by index.

var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(["http://www.bar.com", "http://www.foo.com"]);
responses[0] // Is this response from http://www.bar.com or http://www.foo.com
responses[1] // Is this response from http://www.bar.com or http://www.foo.com

Comment: If these are actually possible invalid urls, you should be muting http exceptions for each request if you want to validate them. To do that you'll need to first get the request for each one, and then pass the array of objects instead of the array of urls. Is the response order still variable in that situation?

Comment: I can't find any existing reports of the responses being in an array index that differs from the index of the associated request on the issue tracker. Provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sven Eller Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When ``["http://www.bar.com", "http://www.foo.com"]`` is used for the fetchAll method, the response is retrieved by the order of ``["http://www.bar.com", "http://www.foo.com"]``. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @SvenEller - have you managed to get around this situation?

Comment: @Tanaike The order you get in responses will not match the order of requests, as fetchAll is asynchronous ([here](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728) is a ref explaining this)